# PyCharm editor and Python console unresolved reference

Tags: python, import, module, pycharm, package

If I have a module in my project with all the inits configured properly and I try to import anything from this module, PyCharm does not identify what I am trying to import. It would work before but somehow it stopped working and I have no idea why.

Example:

./package/file.py

```
def function():
    print('function')
```

./package/__init__.py

```
from .file import function
```

./call.py

```
from package import function

function()
```

The code executes fine but I can't use auto complete and the editor is informing an error "Unresolved reference 'function'" in the file ./call.py

Methods I tried that did not work:

- Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Use different the interpreter (but still using conda)
- CTRL + Space doesn't show anything I need
- Tab doesn't show anything I need
- Restart PyCharm

EDIT0:
If I use `import package` the autocomplete works fine displaying the functions (`package.function`) to use while in the Python Console, but still doesn't work in the editor.

EDIT1:
I tried to mark the directory as Source Root and it did not work

EDIT2:
Tried uninstalling from snap and installing it all back again after removing all files from /home/usr/.PyCharm* and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried uninstalling from snap and installing it all back again after removing all files from /home/usr/.PyCharm* and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark top level directory as a `Source Root`.

*Right-Click* on it, and at the bottom there is an option `Mark Directory as` and choose `Sources Root`. It will turn blue.

Then you can import:

```
from package import function
function()
```

*OR*

```
import package
package.function()
```

Read more at [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/content-root.html#root_types).

Comment: I never had to do this before for it to work fine, but still I did it after this problem and it still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: The [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/content-root.html#root_types) you posted says: "By default, all the files in a content root folder are involved". I don't know it the problem is something related to that.